# abstract method not being picked up

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error: `The type new MyWebViewClient(){} must implement the inherited abstract method MyWebViewClient.launchExternalBrowser()`

```
    DCWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
        public void launchExternalBrowser(String url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I don't understand because according to my code I am defining the method.

```
public abstract class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.url.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        launchExternalBrowser();
        return true;
    }

    public abstract void launchExternalBrowser();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void launchExternalBrowser(String url)
```

is not the same as

```
public abstract void launchExternalBrowser();
```

To satisfy the class implementation, you have to implement a function with the exact same signature as the abstract method. If you want to passing in a string as an argument, you must define the method that was in the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

you are implementing `public void launchExternalBrowser(String url)`
instead of implementing  `public void launchExternalBrowser()`
the difference is in the parameter list of the method

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the `string` parameter in the abstract declaration of `launchExternalBrowser`.

Answer (score 0):

You override the method with *one argument*, while the compiler seems to complain about a method with *no argument*. Maybe you'll need to override both (or just the one without any arguments - depending on the abstract class).

Answer (score 0):

Change the method **launchExternalBrowser()** as like this inside MyWebViewClient like this:

```
public void launchExternalBrowser(){

}
```